# convert 1 dimension strings array into json file

Tags: arrays, json, powershell

Perhaps it's easy question and will be banned but I spend hours today and not make it work as I expected. 
so I have such object:

```
data_1 data_2 ... abra_12 ...
```

I want convert it into json like this:

```
[
    {"data_1" : "data_1"},
    {"data_2" : "data_2"},
    ...
]
```

I tried this:

```
$result = Get-ChildItem $Path2Search -recurse | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=locI(.*)\(\").+?(?=\")' -casesensitive | foreach {$_.matches} | select value | ConvertTo-Json | Out-File $save2file
```

But I'm getting this:

```
{
   "Value":  "data_1"
},
{
   "Value":  "data_2"
},
```

While I want it like this:

```
{
   "data_1":  "data_1"
},
{
   "data_2":  "data_2"
},
```

Any advice how? :)

Answer (score 3):

You can first shape the result in a list of key-values then convert it to json.

For example if your input is a comma separated string, you can use:

```
$input = "data_1, data_2, data_3"
$input.Split(',').Trim() | 
    ForEach-Object {@{$_=$_}} | 
        ConvertTo-Json | 
             Out-File "C:\test.txt"
```

Or if the input is a string array:

```
$input = @("data_1", "data_2", "data_3")
$input | ForEach-Object {@{$_=$_}} | 
        ConvertTo-Json |
            Out-File "C:\test.txt"
```

And the result would be:

```
[
    {
        "data_1":  "data_1"
    },
    {
        "data_2":  "data_2"
    },
    {
        "data_3":  "data_3"
    }
]
```

While I prefer to use above solution for creating json result, but you also can rely on string manipulation as well:

```
$input = "data_1, data_2, data_3"
@"
[ 
`t$(($input -split '\s*,\s*' |%{"{ `"$_`" : `"$_`" }"}) -join ",`n`t")
]
"@
```

Comment: thanks, but in my case they are not comma separated, exactly data feeding from this line of code: 
$result = Get-ChildItem $Path2Search -recurse | Select-String -Pattern '(?<=locI(.*)\(\").+?(?=\")' -casesensitive | foreach {$_.matches} | select value  
any advice how to split it then?

Comment: Just put the array instead of `$input.Split(',').Trim()`

Comment: just put instead of not work, drop error: ConvertTo-Json : The type 'System.Collections.Hashtable' is not supported for serialization or deserialization of a dictionary. Keys must be strings

Comment: I make it work like this: ...foreach {$_.matches} | ForEach-Object -begin {$result = "{"} -process {$result = $result+$_.Value+":"+$_.Value+","} -end {$result = $result+"}"} $result | Out-File $output
but that dont look like nice :/

Comment: How is it related to the code which I shared with you?!

Comment: you code is not working in case of object collection

Comment: We answers what is asked in questions. You shared the input like this: `$result = "data_1, data_2, data_3" ` so I answered that. Since I don't have any idea about your new requirement, can you please ask a new question showing us what you are trying to do exactly?

Comment: I believe the current answer is a suitable and correct answer for the current question :)

Comment: "data_1 data_2 ... abra_12 ..." they not comma separated, its object, if it was comma separated its easy task as for string? Important part of question how to deal with that object collection not with a string. Perhaps misleading was an example that i provided, but its deeper that I expected tbh

Comment: You shared the input like this: `$result = "data_1, data_2, data_3"` now changing it. It makes the question and the answer confusing. It's better to revert the question to the previous version and ask a new one :) Surely you will receive the answer faster.

Comment: I'm not going to change the answer. Because, it is the answer of your original post. Currently in fact it's not clear what is the input, Because `data_1 data_2 ... abra_12 ...` doesn't have any meaning in powershell.

Comment: mate, you are give answer that you think is right, and yes it is but only partially, I dont change question, input was provided from beginning and wasn't include comas, please check, dont see a point to dispute any more, question is still same:  I have such object (not a list!)

Comment: Please take a look at your [first revision](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/47746198/1) and read your code where you said *I try this:* `$result = "data_1, data_2, data_3" `

Comment: Anyway, I put an edit for you using a string array. Read this part of the answer *Or if the input is a string array: ...*. If for any reason it's not what you are looking for, try posting a new question and consider posting a [MCVE].

Comment: Its for you if you dont understand: System.Collections.Hashtable' is not supported for serialization or deserialization of a dictionary. Keys must be strings. I dont have strings, its object. I try to do as strings, but its my try, question is about how to do that from object collection

Comment: I even changed the answer to support the title 'convert 1 dimension strings array into json file'. It seems you have a totally different question. Feel free to ask a new question containing [MCVE].